# Check Constraint with current_date on mysql

Tags: mysql, constraints

This might be a horrible question, but I'm having trouble with a constraint that is supposed to prevent users to be added when they are younger than 18 years old.

The constraint looks like this:
`alter table client add constraint age check(datediff(current_date, born_date)/ 365 >= 18);`

With this, I should get the difference in days between now and the date that the client was born, and by dividing that by 365, we get the number of years.

But when I try to add this constraint, an error message pops up:

*Error Code: 3814. An expression of a check constraint 'age' contains disallowed function: curdate.*

As far as I know, current_date is just a call of the curdate() function. I have also tried other functions like now() and tried to declare a datetime variable outside the check and giving it the now() value, both without success.

I also checked the [w3resource](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/date-and-time-functions.php#:%7E:text=In%20MySQL%20the%20CURDATE(),is%20used%20in%20the%20function.&text=In%20MySQL%20the%20CURRENT_DATE%20returns,is%20used%20in%20the%20function.) for some other date functions but for example localtime() happens to be exactly like now() when I use it instead, or curdate() and current_date()

I'm using mysql 8

Thanks for all the help!

Edit - This has to be done with constraints (this is a question a teacher of mine gave his students to prepare us for an exam comming  up). I also know that constraints only accept deterministic functions, and all the date ones like now() or current_date() are not deterministic. But how can I get the date for "now" inside a constraint, then?

Comment: "prevent users to be added when they are younger than 18 years old." But how to prevent to the user add a fake birth date?

Comment: that is simply not the point. This is not something for an enterprise or anything like that, meaning the only one that will be adding 'clients', as I call them, is me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could try using a different column as the constraint. Add a new column called age, that calculates it beforehand, then add the constraint.

For example:

```
birthdate DATETIME,    
register_time DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
age INT AS (timestampdiff(YEAR,register,birthdate)),
CONSTRAINT person_birthdate CHECK (birthdate is not null),
CONSTRAINT person_age CHECK (age>=18),
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party, but:

It is not allowed to call non deterministic functions in check constrains in MySQL.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35587889)